# How to combine tabs and carousel in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement Twitter Bootstrap Carousel and Tabs. They both look to be functioning alright on the initial load, but as soon I hit one of the carousel arrows, the content goes away (the active class is removed and display is set to none). Can anybody see what the problem could be? [sample page](http://www.owdtsample.com/) (look at the news box at the bottom right of the screen)

Comment: Your website is not working now.

Comment: It should be working, please try again.

Comment: Any chance you could post the original source here since the link is no longer working?  Either that or post it to like JSBin.com or something?  I came across this answer (#3 on Google) and it sucks not being able to see the original code in question.

Comment: @streetlogics Take a look at [this:](http://situs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Control links refers to `#news-box`:

```
<!-- Carousel nav -->
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#news-box" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
<a class="carousel-control pause-play pause" href="#news-box"></a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#news-box" data-slide="next">›</a>
```

But your carousel has no `id`:

```
<div class="carousel slide">
```

Try with:

```
<div class="carousel slide" id="news-box">
```

Comment: Awseome, thanks for that. However, even though the initial issue is resolved, but looks like the carousel is no longer working. Any idea what else may be missing?

Comment: You can't have both carousel playing. The active one should be in play, while the other should be in pause. See: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/1887

Comment: Similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585123/jquery-carousel-stuck-twitter-bootstrap
Another interesting link: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2196

Comment: I tried to implement your solution using the following code, but no luck so far:  
    `$(".nav-tabs a").on("click", function(){  
         var $href = $(this).attr('href');  
         if ( $href == '#news-box-us' ) {  
              var $otherone = '#news-box-europe';  
         }  
         else{  
              var $otherone = '#news-box-us';  
         }  
         //pause the other one, resuem this one  
         $($href).carousel('cycle');  
         $($otherone).carousel('pause');  
    });`

Comment: I also found it a bit problematic. Take in mind that: 1. In JS you don't have to use "$" for the vars 2. If you move the mouse out and into the box, the carousel will automatically stop and restart, also if it was already stopped (to avoid this look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325401/bootstrap-carousel-v2-0-4-restarts-on-mouseleave-event)

Comment: I've started a bounty for a similar question. Try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12397959/1312346

Comment: Thanks Francesco. The solution in that thread looks very promising. I still however seem to be able to break it after I play with that carousel several times.